# Swordigo jump problem

Tags: swordigo

[image]

I am having problems jumping high enough to get the second key in the 'World's End Keep' Stage.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly you have to turn on the Dimensional Rift spell, then it makes a few platforms appear. Heres a screenshot showing the same room you are in but once the spell is activated, the platforms are now visible.

[image: Swordigo]